# Counter Strike GO server query

Tags: php, api, sockets

im trying to create my own server query, but im with a few problems..

[Valve docs](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_Queries)

Im using the A2S_INFO request.

The problem is that im not getting all the informations that i want, like the current number of players, the number of bots..

This is what im getting from the query:

```html
array (size=10)
  0 => string 'ÿÿÿÿI[USA]Arena 1v1|1on1|Aim|Store|' (length=36)
  1 => string 'am_dust_v6' (length=10)
  2 => string 'csgo' (length=4)
  3 => string 'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive' (length=32)
  4 => string 'Ú' (length=4)
  5 => string 'dl' (length=2)
  6 => string '1.35.0.9' (length=9)
  7 => string '¡‡i1v,1vs1,admin,aim,arena,awp,awp dm,community,comp,competitive,deagle,deathmatch,dm,drops,free,free admin,jail,multi,pistols,rpg,secure' (length=137)
  8 => string 'Ú' (length=2)
  9 => string '�����' (length=5)
```

And this is my actual code

```html
$ip = "107.172.18.227";
    $port = "27015";
    
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $ip, $port);
    
    if($result < 0)
        echo "connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) \n";
    
    $data = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x54\x53\x6F\x75\x72\x63\x65\x20\x45\x6E\x67\x69\x6E\x65\x20\x51\x75\x65\x72\x79\x00";
    socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));
    
    $out = socket_read($socket, 4096);

    $serverInfo = explode("\x00", $out, 10);
    
    var_dump($serverInfo);
```

What im doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

i didnt get any help, but i find a solution, so i will share it

```html
 $ip = "188.93.237.11";
    $port = "1344";
    
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $ip, $port);
    
    if($result < 0)
        echo "connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) \n";
    
    $data = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x54\x53\x6F\x75\x72\x63\x65\x20\x45\x6E\x67\x69\x6E\x65\x20\x51\x75\x65\x72\x79\x00";
    socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));
    
    $out = socket_read($socket, 4096);

    
    $queryData         = explode("\x00", substr($out, 6), 5);
    
    $server['name']        = $queryData[0];
    $server['map']         = $queryData[1];
    $server['game']        = $queryData[2];
    $server['description'] = $queryData[3];
    $packet                = $queryData[4];
    $app_id                = array_pop(unpack("S", substr($packet, 0, 2)));
    $server['players']     = ord(substr($packet, 2, 1));
    $server['playersmax']  = ord(substr($packet, 3, 1));
    $server['bots']        = ord(substr($packet, 4, 1));
    $server['dedicated']   =     substr($packet, 5, 1);
    $server['os']          =     substr($packet, 6, 1);
    $server['password']    = ord(substr($packet, 7, 1));
    $server['vac']         = ord(substr($packet, 8, 1));

   var_dump($server);
```

Thank you!